# Well formed formula

Tags: logic

I hope this is the right part of the site to use.
I'm doing some work and covering some old logic formulas that a former (very talented) programmer built - but all the comments refer to the need of 'well formed formulas', I've googled it but I'm trying to see if someone here can explain - in laymans terms! - what a well formed formula is?
I have an ok understanding of certain mathmatical functions and terms - but just trying to reach out to some experts a bit! :)

Comment: Here is a quick [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) on it. It is better than anyone could ever explain on this website.

Comment: @TymaGaidash - thank you. I'm just trying to get my head around someones work who is clearly a lot cleverer than I! :)

Comment: A well-formed formula is simply a syntactically correct expression of the language, exactly as in a programming language: some strings of symbols are "right" and some are wrong". The right ones are those accepted by the interpreter/compiler.